# Count Occurences of Dates Through an Array of different Dates | Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, count

I have a very long data structure that essentially composes of dates. I wanted to count the occurrence of each day in the year, so essentially the number of dates that land on 1/1/16, ... ,12/31/16. I was wondering if there is a way to do this besides looping through my entire loop.

Example:
    dates = [1/1/16, 1/1/16, ... 10/2/16, 10/3/16, 10/3/16,...];
    results = [{1/1/16: 2}, {1/2/16: #},... ];

The results would say be some count of all the occurrences of each date.

Comment: Hopefully the values are strings, not division expressons… ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count all occurences you have to loop through the array.

```
var map = {};

for (var i = 0, l = dates.length; i < l; i++) {
    var date = dates[i];

    map[date] = map[date] ? map[date] + 1 : 1;
}

console.log(map);
```

Comment: You could also use *reduce*: `dates.reduce((obj, d)=>{d in obj? obj[d]++ : (obj[d] = 1); return obj},{})`.

Comment: Is that var(i=0; i=dates.length? or l=dates.length?

Comment: @ajl123 i'm creating two local variables, the index `i` and the  length of the array `l` as it won't change (no elements added or removed) during the loop. Otherwise the length will be checked on every iteration.